# How to ignore "Tags:" Header in mutt (neomutt)

Tags: mutt

I am using NEOMUTT with Virtual folders and added `"ignore *"` to my `.muttrc`.

It ignores all headers apart from the `"Tags:"` header.  I also want to ignore this tag (and all others).

How can I do that?

Comment: I tried to test this behaviour and it works as expected – at lest with the current neomutt version . Don't you have `Tags` listed in unignore command somewhere in your configuration file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround you can use `display_filter` setting

Add to your `.muttrc`:

```
set display_filter="sed -e '/^Tags:.*/d'"
```